# How do I decode xterm responses?

Tags: encoding, terminal, xterm

I'm building an application that uses pty.js to open up a pseudo terminal on my computer. I'm getting responses that look like:

```
]0;ec2-user@ip-172-31-62-237:~[?1034h[ec2-user@ip-172-31-62-237 ~]$ ls
]0;ec2-user@ip-172-31-62-237:~[ec2-user@ip-172-31-62-237 ~]$ pwd
/home/ec2-user
```

I'm assuming pty.js is sending back a specific encoding, but I'm not sure what the encoding is and how to decode it. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those aren't *responses* (the terminal would *respond*), but control sequences sent by an application (not the terminal).  I see a few instances (OSC might print as `^[]`, and CSI as `^[[` if the escape character were shown as **`^[`**):

```
]0;ec2-user@ip-172-31-62-237:~
```

looks like the control for setting the window title (from xterm although several programs support it),

```
OSC Ps ; Pt BEL
OSC Ps ; Pt ST
...
            Ps = 0  -> Change Icon Name and Window Title to Pt.
```

and

```
[?1034h
```

looks like another sequence from xterm's repertoire (generally not supported by other programs):

```
CSI ? Pm h
          DEC Private Mode Set (DECSET).
...
            Ps = 1 0 3 4  -> Interpret "meta" key, sets eighth bit.
          (enables the eightBitInput resource).
```

For the given example, *encoding* isn't a factor.

For capturing output from your application, the [`script`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html) program is useful.  I use a small utility ([unmap](http://invisible-island.net/misc_tools/index.html#item:unmap)) to translate the resulting `typescript` files into readable form, but `cat -v` is often adequate for this purpose.

Further reading: [XTerm Control Sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html)